# Custom Authentication for cloud endpoints with own database user details

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, google-cloud-endpoints, istio

I have gone through the google cloud endpoints documentation and find the below configuration there for custom authentication,

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authenticating-users

I don't understand the below things,

1. How do I configure My spring boot jwt authentication(username and password in database) service url here ?

2.What are the possible values for the below configurations in case of custom authentication

```
x-google-issuer: "issuer of the token"

x-google-jwks_uri: "url to the public key"

x-google-audiences: "YOUR-CLIENT-ID"
```

Can you provide a example for this If any one using this type of authentication?

Answer (score 0):

There are some great resources in response to this existing StackOverflow question:

[Google Cloud Endpoints custom authentication with App Engine Flexible (Node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43901777/google-cloud-endpoints-custom-authentication-with-app-engine-flexible-node-js)

Don't let the specificity of the question deter you. Even though it was asked about AppEngine Flex with Node.js, the answer is language/environment agnostic.